# How to send the $_SESSION variable back to index file from another page?

Tags: php, html, post, session-variables

I have a global variable called `$_SESSION['user_name']` which is set with POST value when I click on the Submit button in a form.

In this php file, I check if `$_SESSION['user_name']` is empty.

If yes, I have to file a form and if no, means the session is still going on and it sends you to the profile.

Anyway, after I fill the form, then it compares this variable if it matches another variable and then heads to the **profile.php** if true.

On this page, I have one button which is meant to "logout" the user.

On pressing, it sends you to another php file where I change the variable
(I have echo-ed it before and it does change it)

but it doesn't forward it back to main page (index.php) and the variable still has the value from the **$_POST** although it is different in logout.php as I change it.

---

Code I have at `logout.php`:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $_SESSION['user_name'] = ""; // makes it empty
  echo $_SESSION['user_name'];
?>
```

And some html where I use meta tag to redirect back to the index.

---

> Now, my question is, how can I forward **the changed** variable back to the index or form page? Or is there any other way of doing that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your logout.php file to something like this:

```
<?

require_once('functions.php');

log_out_user();
header("Location: login.php");
exit;

?>
```

Now in your functions file, for example, try writing this function:

```
function log_out_user() {
   unset($_SESSION['username']);
   // You can also use: session_destroy();
   return true;
}
```

Hope this helps!